# Calling function from custom js library on startup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, startup

I have been working on getting the client date and passing it to the server on loading an aspx page, but a problem has arisen:

I wrote a function called `ClientDate()` in my custom `ppm.js` library, and I wrote some vb.net codebehind which creates a startup JavaScript that calls that function on startup and saves the output to a `textbox`.

It seemed to be working correctly until I decided to change the format of the date returned by `ClientDate()` from `yyyymmdd` to `yyyy-mm-dd`.  The textbox continued to display the date in the old format.  When I changed the function output to `"Hello, World"`, it continued to display the date in the old format, and when I commented out the function completely in the library, it still displayed the date in that format.  Restarting and rebooting the computer have no effect.

Clearly, my page is finding `ClientDate()` someplace else.  I searched my project for `ClientDate()` and found only two occurrences, once in the library and once in the startup JavaScript that calls it.

I can think of 2 possible explanations (but don't believe any of them):

1. There is a built-in JavaScript or jQuery function called `ClientDate()` that is being called instead of mine.
2. There is a hidden file containing an older version of the `ClientDate()` function.

Any ideas how I can track this bug down?

Comment: Have you tried to change the function name and invocation?

Comment: You done a Ctrl-f5 to clear your cache? The js could be being cached by the client.

Comment: If you [debug the js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code) does the function get hit and work as expected?

Comment: In response to the (amazingly swift) responses by borja and Liam:  When I change the function name in the library only, it has no effect on the output.  When I change the function name in the calling javascript, I get nothing in the textbox.  Ctl-f5 produces the usual incorrect output.  The startup javascript runs but does not call the function in my library.  When I put a stop on the first line of the ClientDate() function in my library, the page puts the incorrect output in the textbox without ever stopping.

Comment: When I rename ppm.js to _ppm.js but leave the reference on the page as <script src="Scripts/ppm.js" ...>, squiggly lines appear under "ppm.js", but the file runs without error, returning the incorrectly formatted date. My guess #2 was evidently correct; there is a duplicate /Scripts folder somewhere containing an older version of ppm.js.  Something is directing my page to look for the /Scripts folder in the wrong place.  I have been unable to find either the location of the /Scripts folder or the configuration that is telling my code where to find it.